# Make a get request until a response comes from a request post vue js

Tags: vue.js, axios

I should upload file in my vue.js app. When I browse a file, I make post request and until I get a response, I need to make get request every 2 seconds for example. How can I do this?

```js
uploadFile(event) {
    this.isLoadingProcess = true;

    console.log(this.isLoadingProcess);
    let data = new FormData();

    this.file = event.target.files[0];

    data.append('name', 'uploaded-file');
    data.append('file', event.target.files[0]);
    const options = {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': event.target.files[0].type,
        },
    
        onUploadProgress: function (progressEvent) {
            const {loaded, total} = progressEvent;
            let percentCompleted = Math.floor((loaded * 100) / total);
            //console.log(percentCompleted);
            if (percentCompleted !== 100) {
               axios.get(url, {data: progressId})
                        .then(response => {
                            this.progress = response.data.progress;
                           // console.log(this.progress);
                            console.log(response.data.progress);
                        })
            }
        },
    };
        axios.post(
        url,
        data,
        options
    )
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);

        })
        .finally(()=> {
            this.isLoadingProcess = false;
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

what about this?
It asks api about update more than every 2 seconds, but It's better for my opinion in case, when endpoint isn't available

```js
var processTimeoutFunction = null;

function checkProgress() {
  axios.get('ckeck-process', ...).then(response => {
    if (response.processIsActive) {
      processTimeoutFunction = setTimeout(() => checkProgress(), 2000);
    } else {
      clearTimeout(processTimeoutFunction);
      this.isLoadingProcess = false;

  })
}
```